# How can I import and use android x library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

I want to use a library to take the date from the user.

The project I use needs to add the library and classes from the AndroidX library.

Once I add this project by adding a module or by adding a direct command to gradle, the following error is given :

Link to the used project:
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Error :

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
Failed to resolve: androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
```

build.gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.**********"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileOptions {

        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.1.2'
}
```

If the following commands are added to gradle, the following error will be seen

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

}
```

Error :

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
Failed to resolve: androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
```

I do not have much information about the AndroidX library, but I do not think there are such libraries.

**How can I fix it?**

**Is there a solution to this problem?**

Comment: feel free to accept my answer

Comment: Did you get any simple solution without converting the library code to androidx?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily migrate to AndroidX with the following steps:

**1- first your Android Studio version must be 3.2.+**

**2- from the menu select** *Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX*

The Android Studio will show you the references to be changed.
select `Do Refactor` and wait a few seconds, I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AndroidX in a new project, you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/)

android.useAndroidX: When set to true, the Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.

android.enableJetifier: When set to true, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The flag is false by default if it is not specified.